# Serialising my class is failing because of an eventhandler

Tags: c#, serialization, event-handling

I wasn't expecting to come across this error. I imagine I'm doing something wrong somewhere else.

I have an MVVM application.

My model can serialise its self using a `BinaryFormatter`. This was working fine.

Today I added in an event handler to my model, and the viewmodel that contains the model subscribes to this event.

Now when I try and serialise the model I get an error because my viewmodel isn't serialisable (by design).

I am sure it's down to the subscription to the event, because I've removed the subscription (and only that) and serialisation works again.

I can't apply the `[NonSerialized]` attribute to the handler because it's not a field.

It there a way around this issue?

Comment: For info, this is just one of the many pitfalls with BinaryFormatter. IMO it isn't the ideal serializer. I'd advise you to look at XmlSerializer, DataContractSerializer, or protobuf-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this:

```
[field:NonSerialized]
public event EventHandler MyEvent;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make the event a field like this:

```
    [NonSerialized]
    private EventHandler _eventHandler;

    public event EventHandler MyEvent
    {
        add { _eventHandler += value; }
        remove { _eventHandler -= value; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't know how useful this is, but*...

...extending what Pieter mentioned, you can also have mutliple delegate handlers wrapped into the same event, so you could (theoretically) make your event, in effect, both serializable and non-serializable by doing something like this:

```
[NonSerialized]
private EventHandler _nonSerializableeventHandler;
private EventHandler _eventHandler;

public event EventHandler MyEvent
{
    add
    {
        if (value.Method.DeclaringType.IsSerializable)
            _eventHandler += value;
        else
            _nonSerializableeventHandler += value;
    }
    remove
    {
        {
            if (value.Method.DeclaringType.IsSerializable)
                _eventHandler -= value;
            else
                _nonSerializableeventHandler -= value;
        }
    }
}
```