# How do I seperate a link to get the end of a URL in shell?

Tags: bash, shell, grep

I have some data that looks like this
`"thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/adf4e1"`

I want to know how I can get the trailing part of the URL, I want the output to be
`adf4e1`

I was trying to grep when starting with / and ending with " but I'm only a beginner in shell scripting and need some help.

Comment: Perhaps more importantly, how are you getting that string in the first place? It looks like a JSON fragment; a tool like `jq` may be more suitable for getting the value you want directly from the original.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that using 'cut' command in linux. Cut it using '/' and keep the last cut. Try it, its fun!

Refer http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/cut-command-examples

Comment: How can you use `cut` to get the last parameter?

Comment: @galfisher few options http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22727107/how-to-find-the-last-field-using-cut-linux

Comment: Alternative is - awk -F / '{print $NF}'

Comment: @galfisher `cut -f5 -d/` -- but the `awk` solution is better, as it's more forgiving about multiple delimiters in a row and thus counting field numbers, esp. when the delimiter is space.

Comment: @gilez this `cut` solution only works if the url is exactly of http://.../../... - that's the weakness of `cut` - can't get last column unless you know the exact number of columns (or delimiters), i agree that `awk` is a good solution for this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a quick and dirty solution, using grep (with perl regex) and cut:

```
$ cat file
  "thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/adf4e1"
  "anotherUrl": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979680"
  "thumbnailUrl": "http://facebook.com/12f"
  "randortag": "http://google.com/this/is/how/we/roll/3fk19as1"

$ cat file | grep -o '/\w*"$' | cut -d'/' -f2- | cut -d'"' -f1
  adf4e1
  3979680
  12f
  3fk19as1
```

Comment: Use `cat file | awk -F / '{print $NF}'`

Comment: @dganesh2002 why use `cat` ? and that leaves a `"` at end

Comment: @galfisher, the regex you used doesn't use perl regex and also has the useless use of cat when you can pass the filename directly to grep... a grep solution with perl regex can be `grep -oP '[^/"]+(?="$)' file` avoiding need of cut altogether

Comment: another way would be `grep -oP '.*/\K[^"]+' file`

Answer (score 1):

We could kill this with a thousand little `cut`s, or just one blow from Awk:

```
awk -F'[/"]' '{ print $(NF-1); }'
```

Test:

```
$  echo '"thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/adf4e1"' \
     | awk -F'[/"]' '{ print $(NF-1); }'
adf4e1
```

Filter thorugh Awk using double quotes and slashes as field separators. This means that the trailing part `../adf4e1"` is separated as `{..}</>{adf4e1}<">{}` where curly braces denote fields and angle brackets separators. The Awk variable `NF` gives the 1-based number of fields and so `$NF` is the last field. That's not the one we want, because it is blank; we want `$(NF-1)`: the second last field.

"Golfed" version:

```
awk -F[/\"] '$0=$(NF-1)'
```

Answer (score 1):

If the original string is coming from a larger JSON object, use something like `jq` to extract the value you want.

For example:

```
$ jq -n '{thumbnail: "http://placehold.it/150/adf4e1"}' |
> jq -r '.thumbnail|split("/")[-1]'
adf4e1
```

(The first command just generates a valid JSON object representing the original source of your data; the second command parses it and extracts the desired value. The `split` function splits the URL into an array, from which you only care about the last element.)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do this purely in bash using string replacement and substring removal if you wrap your string in single quotes and assign it to a variable.

```
#!/bin/bash

string='"thumbnailUrl": "http://placehold.it/150/adf4e1"'
string="${string//\"}"
echo "${string##*/}"

adf4e1 #output
```

Comment: no need of using `echo` in second command.. just use `string="${string//\"}"`